# How to retrieve image from oracle sql and show it in jsp page?

Tags: java, image, oracle, jsp, servlets

**Servlet Code :**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

public class profile_photo extends HttpServlet {

    /**
     * The doGet method of the servlet. <br>
     *
     * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to get.
     * 
     * @param request the request send by the client to the server
     * @param response the response send by the server to the client
     * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
     * @throws IOException if an error occurred
     */
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        HttpSession ses=request.getSession();
        String email = (String)ses.getAttribute("ses_email");
        String imgLen="";
        Connection cn;
        PreparedStatement ps;   
        try
        {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:sm","system","gecbsp");
            ps=cn.prepareStatement("select photo_loc from smreg3 where email = "+
                                "'"+email+"'");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                  imgLen = rs.getString(1);
                  System.out.println(imgLen.length());
                  }  
            ps=cn.prepareStatement("select photo_loc from smreg3 where email = "+
                    "'"+email+"'");
            ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs2.next()){
                  int len = imgLen.length();
                  byte [] rb = new byte[len];
                  InputStream readImg = rs2.getBinaryStream(1);
                  int index=readImg.read(rb, 0, len);  
                  System.out.println("index"+index);
                  ps.close();
                  response.reset();
                  response.setContentType("image/jpg");
                  response.getOutputStream().write(rb,0,len);
                  response.getOutputStream().flush();  
                  }
                  }
                  catch (Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  }

    }
```

**Jsp code :**

```
<img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/profile_photo" />
```

**Error :**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:573)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:183)
at profile_photo.doGet(profile_photo.java:59)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:263)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:584)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

**Questions:**

How to retrieve image in JSP from ImageServlet?
Is the above method correct way to retrieve image from database? Or is there better way?

Comment: Unrelated but: you should not use the JDBC/ODBC bridge. It's buggy slow and has been removed in Java 8. Use a real JDBC driver instead. And don't open a new connection on each request. Use a connection pool instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you declare `out` but don't seem to use it, you should probably remove the line

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

You can not call `getOutputStream()` on a response once you did a call to `getWriter()`.

Comment: @RavindraBairagi then you may want to accept the answer

Comment: @RavindraBairagi you should still be able to accept answers to a question you asked. If I understand [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) correctly this works by clicking the check-mark under the vote-counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try below change

response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
response.setContentLength(len);
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(rb,0,len);           
outputStream.flush();
```

Comment: While this may help, shouldn't you also remove `PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();` as it seems the variable is not used and the function is explicitly named in the exception?